# how to hide background listview in my header and footer layout design?

Tags: android, listview, background, transparency

I created one listview application then I decide to design header and footer for the listview my problem is my header and footer showing my listview in background. i wish to hide this header and footer listview items so help me how to hide?

code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity { 
    private SettingsAdapter setAdap;
    private SettingsInnerAdapter setInnerAdap;
    private ListView lstView;
    int top;
    private int mSelPosition = 0;
    private boolean innerListView = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

        setContentView(R.layout.testing);
        int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        ImageView imgHead = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        ImageView imgbottom = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


        imgbottom.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
        imgbottom.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/8, height/8));


        imgHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
        imgHead.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/8, height/8));

        setAdap = new SettingsAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
        setAdap.updateImageSize(width, height);
        setAdap.setTextVisible(0);
       setAdap.setInnerViewVisible(false);


        lstView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstLeft);
    lstView.setScreenDimension(width/16, height / 4 , width, height / 2);
        lstView.setAdapter(setAdap);
        lstView.setSelected(false);

      }
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/blue">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_black"
        android:id="@+id/ttest"

        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55px"

        android:background="@drawable/gradient_black"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ssss"
        />  



    </RelativeLayout>
  <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstLeft"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textHead"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstRight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
        </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give id's to your `Header View Layout` and to your `Footer View Layout` then set these properties for your both `ListView's`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstRight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerViewId"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerViewId"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
</ListView>
```